# concat in mysql using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my application every user can like every comment.But each like is entered as comma seperated form.User id of each users like entered into database as 2,4,5..etc.I use concat in my model like this

```
        public function shop_like($shop_id,$user_id,$logged_id)
        { 
            $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);

            $this->db->where('shop_id', $shop_id);
            $this->db->set('review_like', 'review_like+1', FALSE);
            $where = "CONCAT('like_user_id', ',','".$logged_id."')"; 
           // $where = CONCAT(like_user_id,'".$logged_id."');
            $this->db->set('like_user_id', $where);
            $this->db->set('review_like', 'review_like+1', FALSE);
            $this->db->update('shop_reviews',$data);
          }
```

Each like, the like_user_id field contain the inserted value like this CONCAT(like_user_id, ',','7') this is the problem

I want the existing comma seperated values and the user id of liked user

plzz correct the syntax of concat

Comment: What is the problem? Are you not able to select the likes?

Comment: each like my db value is CONCAT(like_user_id, ',','7').

Comment: Please elaborate this `---->` `$where = "CONCAT('like_user_id', ',','".$logged_id."')"; ` what you want to achieve over here and what you were getting while doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the column you use `set()` and not in where clause:

```
$this->db->set("like_user_id", "CONCAT( like_user_id, ',".$logged_id."' )", false);
```

Comment: Are you updating or selecting values in your query? The above question is updating some table.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
    public function shop_like($shop_id,$user_id,$logged_id)
    { 
        $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);

        $this->db->where('shop_id', $shop_id);
        $this->db->set('review_like', 'review_like+1', FALSE);
        $where = "CONCAT(like_user_id, ',','".$logged_id."')"; 
        $this->db->set('like_user_id', $where, false);
        $this->db->set('review_like', 'review_like+1', FALSE);
        $this->db->update('shop_reviews',$data);
      }
```

Comment: try this but like is not increment & no change

Comment: print your last query `echo $this->db->last_query();`